# Qt Cannot load plugin : undefined symbol iPlugin::staticMetaObject

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, symbols

I'm trying to have a plugin system in my qt program.

Even if I think my code is good, I still have a linking error in the main program.
I'm using **QPluginLoader** to load the plugin. The method **instantiate** returns a null pointer and the error string is :

```
Cannot load library *library* : (*library*: undefined symbol: _ZN7iPlugin16staticMetaObjectE)
```

Here is the interface iPlugin.h :

```
#ifndef IPLUGIN_H
#define IPLUGIN_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtPlugin>

class QWidget;

class iPlugin : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    virtual ~iPlugin() {}
    virtual const QString &getName() const = 0;
    virtual QWidget *onStart() = 0;

public slots:
    virtual void onMenu() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(iPlugin, "Project.iPlugin")

#endif // IPLUGIN_H
```

The plugin file textplugin.h

```
#ifndef TEXTPLUGIN_H
#define TEXTPLUGIN_H

#include <QObject>

#include "iplugin.h"

class QString;

class TextPlugin : public iPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(iPlugin)

public:
    TextPlugin();
    virtual ~TextPlugin();
    const QString &getName() const;
    QWidget *onStart();

public slots:
    void onMenu();

private:
    const QString _name;
};

#endif // TEXTPLUGIN_H
```

And the plugin file textplugin.cpp :

```
#include <QString>

#include "textplugin.h"
#include "textwidget.h"

#include <iostream>

TextPlugin::TextPlugin() :
    _name("text")
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

TextPlugin::~TextPlugin()
{
}

const QString &TextPlugin::getName() const
{
    return (this->_name);
}

QWidget *TextPlugin::onStart()
{
    return (new TextWidget);
}

void TextPlugin::onMenu()
{

}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(plug_text, TextPlugin)
```

Does anyone have an idea ?
I'm stuck on it for about 6 hours, I'm going crazy.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : I moved on Qt5, using **Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "Project.plug_text")** in my class declaration and deleting **Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(plug_text, TextPlugin)** of the cpp file but nothing have changed, the error is the same.

EDIT2 : I have forgotten the **QPluginLoader** code, here it is :

```
QPluginLoader loader("/home/bambou/build-TestPlugin-Desktop-Debug/plugin/libplug_text.so");
if (QObject *obj = loader.instance()) {
    std::cout << "hello !" << std::endl;
    iPlugin *plugin = qobject_cast<iPlugin *>(obj);
    this->registerPlugin(file, plugin);
} else {
    std::cout << loader.errorString().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, it is really difficult to say without seeing the code that reproduces the problem, including the QPluginLoader.

Comment: You still hide important details like `"*absolute path to the lib, for debugging purposes*"`, please do not obfuscate these.

Comment: I have added the path.

Comment: Have you verified the path with QLibary::isLibrary()? Also, the errorString() cannot possibly return what you are writing based on its source code. Can you post a self-compilable example that reproduces the error?

Comment: I have verified the path with QLibrary::isLibrary, it returns true. What do you expect by "self-compilable example" ? errorString returns exactly the same string, I have just obfuscated the path, the exact value is :
    Cannot load library /home/bambou/build-TestPlugin-Desktop-Debug/plugin/libplug_text.so: (/home/bambou/build-TestPlugin-Desktop-Debug/plugin/libplug_text.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7iPlugin16staticMetaObjectE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem, my bad.
For those who will have this problem : I had an INCLUDEDIR line in my plugin's .pro file, I have removed it and now, the plugin works well.